# SoapException: Server was unable to read request

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I have created a **web service using Microsoft C#** and i was able to hosted it in  a remote server consume it using a **C# Desktop client**

But end client who uses a **SAP** interface is unable to use this web service and getting the following errors.

[image]

As the input parameters user has to input a class complex as this :

This is the **SOAP 1.1** request and response

```
POST Webservice.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 122.255.30.74
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "xxxx"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <SendEmail xmlns="xxxx">
      <toDetails>
        <EmailAddress>
          <Email>string</Email>
          <Name>string</Name>
        </EmailAddress>
        <EmailAddress>
          <Email>string</Email>
          <Name>string</Name>
        </EmailAddress>
      </toDetails>
      <CC>
        <EmailAddress>
          <Email>string</Email>
          <Name>string</Name>
        </EmailAddress>
        <EmailAddress>
          <Email>string</Email>
          <Name>string</Name>
        </EmailAddress>
      </CC>
      <BCC>
        <EmailAddress>
          <Email>string</Email>
          <Name>string</Name>
        </EmailAddress>
        <EmailAddress>
          <Email>string</Email>
          <Name>string</Name>
        </EmailAddress>
      </BCC>
      <subject>string</subject>
      <Item>
        <Items>
          <ID>DateTime</ID>
          <Key>string</Key>
          <ChangedUser>string</ChangedUser>
        </Item>
        <Items>
          <ID>DateTime</ID>
          <Key>string</Key>
          <ChangedUser>string</ChangedUser>
        </Item>
      </Items>
    </SendEmail>
  </soap:Body>
```

What might be the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is choking on one of the datetime fields. Try sending a valid datetime where you currently have dateTime text.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer but im really not clear ! is it a issue with a DateTime field , should i required to send it as a string ?

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify: somewhere in the schema, there is at least one value that expects a dateTime, but you are sending an empty string in this value, which is failing on import. You should examine the schema and see where this might be occurring.